# how do I align RadioSelect button?

Tags: python, html, css, django

For some reason this button comes with weird alignment, I want it aligned next to gender label but the ul element comes with pre existing "margin-block-start, margin-block-end and padding-inline-start" so how do I align it right?

html

```
    <div class="block">
      <label>Gender</label>
      <span class="placer">{{ form.gender }}</span>
    </div>
```

css

```
#id_gender li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

forms.py

```
gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=True)
```

[image: what it looks like right now:]

[image: the ul element info]

I want the radios(Male and Female) to be aligned next to Gender. Thnx in advance!

Comment: is that ok to add this class ? : .placer{float:left;}

Comment: you change `li` but you should also change `ul`

Comment: @furas tried it doesn't work

Comment: you have to change both `li` and `ul`. Both should be `display: inline-block` or `display:  inline`. And maybe `label` will also need `display: inline-block`. I can't run it to see what CSS it uses for all elements.

Comment: @farus Alright thanks a lot man! it works, needed to align the "placer" class.